# Opencart 1.5.6 How to show price, with and without tax in shopping cart?

Tags: php, opencart, shopping-cart

I want to show the individual price of each product, tax included and tax excluded on the shopping cart page. I configured opencart to display prices including tax, but I want to add a column to show the price without tax. I have Opencart 1.5.6. Please can someone help me ?. I tried to modify `cart.php` and `cart.tpl` but I have not succeeded, `$price_extax` shows last price in all products in shopping cart. Thank You.

In `cart.tpl` I added following code:
It shows column tittle:

```
<td class="price"><?php echo "Price ex-tax"; ?></td>
```

It shows price:

```
<td class="price"><?php echo $price_extax; ?></td>
```

In cart.php I added following code:

```
$this->data['price_extax'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'],$product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))/1.12); //My code (tax is 12%)
```

Comment: Perhaps if you post the code you tried someone can offer a fix or suggestion for improvement.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this: `<td class="price"><?php echo "Price ex-tax"; ?></td>`??? Isn't this `<td class="price">Price ex-tax</td>` enough? Maybe some advanced learning of PHP, HTML, CSS, JS (and recommended is MySQL as well!) should happen before you start implementing something in bigger applications... **This is your price excl. tax:** find this line `$this->data['products'][] = array(` and add a new line into this array: `'price_extax' => $product['price'],` - this is it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a single variable or property and expect it to magically become part of the product array.  Learning some php basics will go a long way.

Also, there is no need to use tax method here if your goal is to omit taxes.  You can simply use the currency->format method without it.

You need to make `price_extax` part of the product array. Immediately *after* `$this->data['products'][] = array(` add something like:

```
'extax' => $this->currency->format($product['price']),
```

Then your table cell should hold `$product['extax']`

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Thanks to **billynoah** and **shaddyx** for your help. The solution to the problem, which has worked for me is:

In `catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php` I added (only commented line //):

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
                'extax'           => $this->currency->format($product['price']), //Gets Price tax excluded
```

In `catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/cart.tpl` I added (only commented lines //):

```
<td class="price"><?php echo $column_price; ?></td>
<td class="price"><?php echo "Price (tax excluded)"; ?></td> //Shows column tittle
<td class="total"><?php echo $column_total; ?></td>
```

and

```
<td class="price"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
<td class="price"><?php echo $product['extax']; ?></td>  //Shows price tax excluded
<td class="total"><?php echo $product['total']; ?></td>
```